# iOS multiple pangestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a View as the baseView and I add a panRegconizer named : basePan;
then add a tableview on baseView, when scroll it to a point (assume the bottom)
I disable the scroll and userInteractionEnabled = NO; I hope the basePan could continue handle the touch events and move the tableview by pan point. but seems when disable the scroll the whole touch event is cancel by system.
any method to pass the touch to base down view or panRegconizer,

I tried to make another view(tView) on base view and add second panRegconizer on tView;
when pan on it, basePan doesn't do the job,

how could I transit the touch event to multiple regconizers, I know the touchbegin touchmove touchEnd could be passed to next responder. but nowadays , panregonizer seems easier to use and recommended by apple.

Comment: you have setter userInteractionEnabled = NO;  so no gesture will work

Comment: thanks Girl, I know userinteractionEnable can do this, but my problem is Im dragging my tableview and when it scrolls to bottom I set userInteractionEnabled to NO, and continue dragging, panReg doesn't handle current dragging, unless you release your finger and drag again pan could read your touch